# getting the minor diagonal elements for every group of data in R

Tags: r, for-loop, diagonal

Dataset consist of 3 character variables and 21 numeric variables in time series format.

```
 A,B,C,num_1,num_2,num3_.......num_21


Below is sample data 
   Variable1    Variable2   Variable3   Variable4   Variable5   Variable6   Variable7   Variable8   Variable9   Variable10  Variable11
1   2005    A   X   1AX 1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1   2006    A   X   1AX 2   0   0   0   0   0
1   2007    A   X   1AX 3   0   0.02    0   0.04    0.06
1   2008    A   X   1AX 4   0   0.03    0.04    0.09    0.13
1   2009    A   X   1AX 5   0.01    0.05    0.08    0.16    0.27
1   2010    A   X   1AX 6   0.01    0.04    0.15    0.29    0.42
1   2011    A   X   1AX 7   0.01    0.03    0.12    0.26    0.4
1   2012    A   X   1AX 8   0   0.04    0.15    0.3 0.44
1   2013    A   X   1AX 9   0.01    0.04    0.1 0.17    0.27
1   2014    A   X   1AX 10  0.01    0.05    0.1 0.14    0.21
1   2007    A   Y   1AY 1   0.01    0.04    0.15    0.29    0.42
1   2008    A   Y   1AY 2   0.01    0.03    0.12    0.26    0.4
1   2009    A   Y   1AY 3   0   0.04    0.15    0.3 0.44
1   2010    A   Y   1AY 4   0.01    0.04    0.1 0.17    0.27
1   2011    A   Y   1AY 5   0   0.04    0.15    0.3 0.44
1   2012    A   Y   1AY 6   0.01    0.04    0.1 0.17    0.27
1   1983    B   Y   1BY 1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1   1984    B   Y   1BY 2   0   0.5 0   0   0
```

I have to get the minor diagonal elements for each group of Variable1,3,4

Variable 5 is the concatenation of Variable1,3,4 and variable6 to increment the occurrence of the concatenated variable.

```
 newdata$variable5<-apply(newdata,1 ,function(x) paste0(toString(x[1]), toString(x[3]), toString(x[4])))

 DT<-data.table(newdata)

 DT[ , variable6:= 1:.N , by = c("variable5") ]
 keys<-unique(unlist(DT$variable5))

 for (i in 2:length(keys)){
  data_1<-subset(DT,merge=keys[i])

 result<-diag(data_1[nrow(data_1):1,])
}
```

I am getting the below error

```
  Error in diag(data_1[nrow(data_1):1, ]) : 
 (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Comment: Please remember to include reproducible data

Comment: I am not sure why this is off topic. If the question is not clear, I will rephrase it again with a sample data